# referencing cell value in power Query from different worksheet

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to create several workbooks with power query which pulls prices for respective `CustomerCode`.
I want to pull data based on a cell value from a different worksheet in that workbook

let's say I have `sheet1` `cell("H9").value` where it has the customer code, and another worksheet `Price` with power query.

in the power query formula, I have hard coded as below,

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([CustomerCode] = 123456))
```

but I want this `CustomerCode` to be a variable, referencing `sheet1` `Cell("H9").value`,

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([CustomerCode] = sheet1.Cell("H9").value ))
```

so when I create different workbooks with changed value in `sheet1` `Cell("H9").value`, it will automatically pull the data for respective `CustomerCode` without having to go in the query to change the `CustomerCode`

I am quite new to power query, can it be done in power query formula?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a cell address, but you can access data from a **Named Range**

So, if `Customer_Code` refers to:  `Sheet1!H9`, you can use, in your code:

```
CustomerCode = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Customer_Code"]}[Content][Column1]{0}
```

Comment: This works with a named cell in the same way, a named cell is simply a range of 1 row and 1 column

Comment: @ChrisSchaller As I showed in my example.  Were you confused about that?

Comment: Just adding clarity, I thought your answer was spot on and voted for it. On CodeMentor I received a request regarding how to implement your solution on a single named cell, not a range... because you specifically called it a `Named Range` and then the previous statement _"I don't know"_ just added uncertainty. I'm happy to take their money for the time, but thought I'd just add something to try to disambiguate your concise solution.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller  The definitions I've seen for `Range` in Excel have always referred to **one or more** cells.  Given the knowledge of the assumed target audience for **this** forum, explaining that seemed unnecessary.  Obviously not true for other forums.  And the *I don't know* refers to using a cell address in PQ (eg A1), not a named range.  I don't believe it is possible to use a cell address directly.  But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.  Kudos for explaining it in another forum